# How can I use the same IP from the Internet and intranet?

Tags: ssh, networking, iptables, routing

I have an Ubuntu firewall box (Alma), at the office, with a web server on it.  It looks like this:

```
[Internet] <-> [DSL Router] <-> [Alma]
                                   |
                  [DMZ:10.1...] <--+--> [Internal LAN:192...]
```

Whenever I am at home, outside of Alma, I can get to it just fine through SSH.  When I am inside, on the internal LAN I cannot use the public IP address to log in to the box, but instead must use the local subnet 192...  Alma has 3 NIC interfaces.

I'd like to be able to script some things using a single public IP address.  Let's say it is 7.7.7.7.  This problem prevents doing that easily.  Is there a way to make this command:

```
ssh 7.7.7.7
```

work from inside on the 192 subnet as well as the internet?  The odd thing is that I can ping 7.7.7.7 from inside or outside just fine.  But when I try to SSH to 7.7.7.7 from inside, the connection is refused.

What am I doing wrong, or not doing correctly?

My SSH daemon listens on 0.0.0.0.  The firewall logs no attempt at all when I try from inside.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your firewall blocking outgoing SSH traffic?

Comment: I have to ask is there any reason why you are even allowing SSH traffic into your firewall from outside?  And secondly is there any reason why you just won't alias a hostname to external address when you are home and internal address when you are at work?

Comment: Sounds like a NAT Loopback issue , whats the model of your router?

Comment: Kevin, my firewall is not blocking ssh traffic.  I can ssh to any open host on the net.

Comment: Karlson, I allow ssh traffic into my firewall because I want to be able to administer/make changes to stuff at the office from home.  Aliasing a hostname can be done but that means whenever I move between office and home I have to edit the hosts file.  I can do that but I'd rather not.  I should be able to access a given IP address the same way, whether I'm inside or outside the LAN.

Comment: Steve, my router is a Westell 7500.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would bo  set up a local dns server and use names instead of ip addresses. The concept is called Split horizon DNS. your-machine.yourdomain.com would resolve to 10.0.0.7 locally, and 7.7.7.7 when used externally.

See also:  [Split horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS)

And I personally would recommend to use [djbdns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Djbdns) (or a fork of it) and not bind.

Comment: reto, I'm familiar with Split Horizon DNS.  I'd rather solve the real issue instead of trying to work around it.  It just seems to me that I should be able to do this without a workaround.

Comment: NAT is ugly.. it should have never been invented.

Comment: I cannot disagree with that.  It does seem like its trying to do double NAT.  NAT out to public IP, NAT in to firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure Alma to do destination NATing for the public IP address when accessed from internal LANs.

Say 7.7.7.7 is the public address and 192.168.2.1 the local IP.
Then put these lines on iptables config:

-A PREROUTING -d 7.7.7.7 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.1

any packet for 7.7.7.7 from local LAN will be rerouted (with destination NATing) to 192.168.2.1